# Find indefinite integral $\int \frac{\arcsin (x)}{x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{\arcsin (x)}{x^2}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
$$\frac {1}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}+2\int \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I try to integrate by parts method, but its doesnt want to be solved. I try to substitue $x=\sin u \mathrm{d}x=\cos u$ but failed somewhere

Comment: This is not an integration by parts.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Barcsin(x)%2Fx%5E2,x%5D

Comment: @tired i have an answer key

Comment: I think he is not almost there. The correct integration by parts gives $-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin (x)+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Comment: Note that the answers below may not match the answer key because there are many different forms for the final answer  (all of which are correct because they differ from each other by a constant).

Comment: @MichaelBurr,if we compare the answer from the link of tired, ur answer consist of $$-\frac{arcsin(x)}{x}-ln(\sqrt {1-x^2}+1)$$  but i dont think that $$ln(\sqrt {1-x^2}-1)$$ can be equal to the $lnx$ even if we multiply something to $1/2$.I `m fresh at math, be free to rectify me.

Comment: I've added the explanation as to why the solutions are the same (log rules can be sneaky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\arcsin x$ and $dv=\frac{dx}{x^2}$. Then we will get (see Michael Burr answer. He used partial fractions and mine is trigo substitution)
$$\int \frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}dx=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Let $x=\sin \theta$. Then $dx=\cos\theta\ d\theta$ and $$\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos\theta.$$ Thus,
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\arcsin x}{x^2}dx&=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}+\int\frac{\cos\theta\ d\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\
&=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}+\int \csc\theta\ d\theta\\
&=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-\ln|\csc\theta+\cot\theta|+C\\
&=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-\ln\left| \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right|+C\\
&=-\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-\ln\left|1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|+\ln|x|+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = \arcsin x$ and life will be good.  (Change $\cos(u)/\sin^2 u$ into $\csc u \cot u.$)

Answer (score 2):

$\int \frac{\arcsin(x)}{x^2}dx=\int \arcsin(x) d(-\frac{1}{x})=-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)+\int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{1-x^2}}= -\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)+\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}}=-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)+\int \frac{d(-\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}}=-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)-\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}=-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)-\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2-1})=-\frac{1}{x}\arcsin(x)-\ln(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{(1/x)^2-1})$

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
$$
\int\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x^2}dx.
$$
We may use integration by parts where
\begin{align*}
u&=\arcsin(x)&dv&=\frac{dx}{x^2}\\
du&=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}&v&=-\frac{1}{x}.
\end{align*}
In this case,
$$
\int\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x^2}dx=-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-\int-\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}.
$$
Focusing on the last term, we would like to use $u$-substitution, $u^2=1-x^2$ so that $2udu=-2xdx$.  In other words, $dx=-\frac{udu}{x}$.  Note that in this substitution, it only makes sense when $1-x^2\geq 0$, i.e., $|x|\leq 1$ and we may assume that $u$ is positive.  Using this substitution, we get the integral
$$
\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{u^2}}\cdot\frac{-udu}{x}=-\int\frac{u}{|u|}\frac{du}{x^2}=-\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}=-\int\frac{du}{1-u^2}.
$$
We can now use partial fractions decomposition noting that
$$
\frac{1}{1-u^2}=\frac{1}{2(1-u)}+\frac{1}{2(1+u)}
$$
This ends up being
$$
-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-u|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|1+u|\right).
$$
Now, finally, combine everything and you have your integral (near $x=0$).  After substitution, one gets 
$$
-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|
$$
whose derivative is $\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x^2}$ (checked with Maple).

Comparing this with the accepted answer, we can use log rules to get
$$
-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1-\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|=-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|.
$$
Multiplying the numerator and denominator of the argument to the logarithm by the conjugate of the numerator, we get
$$
-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{1-(1-x^2)}{(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})^2}\right|=-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|^2.
$$
Using log rules the $2$'s cancel and we can break up the logarithm, leaving 
$$
-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}+\ln\left|\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right|=-\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-\ln\left|1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right|+\ln\left|x\right|
$$
Finally, remember $+C$.

Comment: I am not sure that the solution to the last integral is correct.

Comment: @kmitov Can you elaborate on your concern?  I have checked the solution with maple and is has the correct derivative.